# Why isn't NHibernate tracking changes made to my entities?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, fluent-nhibernate, ninject

I'm using Ninject, Fluent NHibernate and ASP.NET MVC.

Up until now everything has been working fine, I don't get any errors and I'm able to query out of the repositories just fine, but I'm not able to commit any changes.

My controller method looks like this

```
[HttpPost]
[UnitOfWork]
public ActionResult Method(int id)
{
    // Lookup entity, toggle a bool property on it and that is it
}
```

My UnitOfWork attribute looks like this

```
public class UnitOfWorkAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        NHibernateSession.Current.BeginTransaction();
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.Exception == null && NHibernateSession.Current.Transaction.IsActive)
        {
            NHibernateSession.Current.Transaction.Commit();
        }
    }
}
```

Both methods are being called and no errors are raised, the problem is that when `NHibernateSession.Current` (which just returns `NHibernate.ISession`) is called, `ISession.IsDirty()` is false. NHibernate doesn't think anything has changed.

I've used similar setups in other projects before without a problem, the only difference with this one is that I swapped out StructureMap for Ninject, which I'm not that familiar with.

The relevant Bindings are

```
Bind<IEntityRepository>().To<EntityRepository>().InRequestScope();
Bind<ISessionFactory>().ToMethod(x => NHibernateSession.CreateSessionFactory()).InSingletonScope();
Bind<ISession>().ToMethod(x => x.Kernel.Get<ISessionFactory>().OpenSession()).InRequestScope();
```

Any ideas what I've done wrong? I'm guessing it has something to do with me messing up on the session handling, but I'm not sure exactly what.

Edit: This is what the Current call returns. The session should be stored so that a new session doesn't have to be created each time.

```
public static ISession Current
{
  get
  {
      var session = GetExistingSession();

      if (session != null)
        return session;

      session = _sessionFactory.OpenSession();
      HttpContext.Current.Items[SessionKey] = session;
      return session;
   }
 }
```

Comment: How do you inject ISession into NHibernateSession.Current?

Comment: It's not really injected. A method is called that will build a SessionFactory and store it in a field in my NHibernateSession class. So `.Current` will call `SessionFactory.OpenSession` if it needs to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the same ISession for that request, hence the `InRequestScope()`. You could change NHibernateSession.Current to something like `return DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<ISession>();` but it's probably more preferred to ctor inject the ISession into the FilterAttribute and tell ninject about it with `this.BindFilter<UnitOfWorkFilter>(FilterScope.Action, 0);`

https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc/wiki/Filter-configurations

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I think my comment was misleading. Could you please see the update? `GetExistingSession()` will return the same session on each call.

Comment: ok, that is basically re-implementing InRequestScope(). Which ISession is the action method using? Is it also using `Current`?

Comment: the controller doesn't have a reference, but the Repository does have one injected into its constructor. I think you're correct, the code from my NhibernateSession class was taken from a previous project that used StructureMap where this was necessary. It probably doesn't work so well with Ninject instead.

Comment: ohhhh I see...yes, the repo would be using a seperate ISession that it got from ninject. Answer is valid.

Comment: The DependencyResolver solution works perfect. I'll play around with Filters as well if that is the better solution. Thank you so much.

Comment: good to hear, BindFilter is nice because all my actions need a transaction so I can globally bind the filter to every action (then you don't need to include the UoW attribute on every action).

Comment: How exactly do I get a reference to BindFilter though?  It doesn't exist in NinjectModule. I have the Ninject.Web and Ninject.Web.Mvc 3 nuget packages installed...

Comment: it's an extension method on IBindingRoot...should be able to do `this.BindFilter` from within the module.

Answer (score 1):

From your comment on your question, I think each time you call `NHibernateSession.Current` you're getting a new session.  That's the problem.  Your session needs to have per-web-request lifetime semantics.  You'll want to inject the session into your controller or your filter.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, could you please see the update? I should have been more clear on what I meant by "if it needs to". OpenSession shouldn't be getting called each time. When I'm debugging `GetExistingSession()` will return the same session.